# Will multi-threading necessarily decrease runtime?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

If I have a series of CPU-intensive operations, will multi-threading my program necessarily decrease its runtime? What are the trade-offs of doing so? In this case, I'm trying to compute the nullspace of a very large matrix. I'm using Python and, specifically, the numpy package:

```
def nullspace(A, eps=1e-15):
    """Computes the null space of the real matrix A."""
    n, m = shape(A)
    if n > m :
        return nullspace(transpose(A), eps)
    _, s, vh = linalg.svd(A)
    s = append(s, zeros(m))[0:m]
    null_mask = (s <= eps)
    null_space = compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
    return null_space.tolist()
```

Also, I would be interested to know just *how* one would go about multi-threading such a function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming?

Comment: @katrielalex No I haven't, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which only allows one thread to interact with the interpreter at a time -- effectively, this means that you can only run one thread of Python at a time. This is a severe disadvantage when trying to run multiple threads.

**However**, `numpy` is built on top of a heavily-optimised library for numerical linear algebra called LAPACK. If you install the right version of LAPACK for your system, it will parallelise its computations for you. You can then install `numpy` on top of your LAPACK, and the Python computations will be parallelised.

This also means that many `numpy` operations release the GIL, so that you can fire off a long `numpy` computation in a Python thread and simultaneously execute other Python. <sub>Thanks @JFSebastian.</sub>

Comment: you should mention explicitly that `numpy` can release GIL and therefore `numpy` can utilize multiple CPUs. GIL only prevents touching *Python objects* simultaneously by different threads. It doesn't prevent their simultaneous execution. Therefore long computations on large matrices in C/Fortran invoked from Python can run in parallel.

Comment: BLAS is important too, especially since LAPACK is typically built on top of BLAS.

Answer (score 2):

No. For one thing, CPU-bound programs rarely benefit at all from threading in Python because of the Global Interpreter Lock.

Also, on a single-core machine, threading won't reduce runtime at all.

Comment: True, although the question is whether threading will "necessarily" reduce runtime; it might, or it might stay the same or increase.

Answer (score 1):

Usually GIL is an impediment for getting benefits of multithreading except for cases when your calculations are being made out of your python interpreter (for example C implementations). I'm not sure if this relates to `numpy`.

If you're running not so many threads you should have a look at [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module. You'll have a separate system process instead of a python thread.